# cast object to enum JAVA

Tags: java, enums

I have to iterate over `myEnum.values()` with only knowing that `myEnum` implement specific `interface`
lets assume that I have interface `statsInterface` 
I have few enums that implement this interface

```
enum statsfromMachine1
enum statsfromMachine2
..
```

later I want to iterate over .
what am I thinking of is somthing like

```
public void interfaceEnumImplParser (statsInterface _interface ,object _myinterfaceImplEnum, string Input) {
    for ((_interface)_myinterfaceImplEnum iterable_element : _myinterfaceImplEnum.values()) {
        //do stuff here
    }
}
```

But I'm missing something here and it won't even compile
Is it possible to do?

Comment: **Side note** on your code: you are repeatedly violating the java naming conventions. Interface should be Camel case, so it is StatsInterface; and I am not sure if you really meant to say "object". In order to help with your question; please the error messages, too.

Comment: Another question: why are you using enums to implement interfaces? Maybe we should step back for a second and you try to explain **why** you think your design should look like this.

Comment: @EddyG I working(as a member of a team) on VERY large code that has this kind of implementation .

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to cast the `enum` into the interface type directly in iteration. If that is true then you should modify your code into something like this.

```
public void interfaceEnumImplParser (statsInterface _interface ,object _myinterfaceImplEnum, string Input) {
    for (_interface iterable_element : _myinterfaceImplEnum.values()) {
        //do stuff here
    }
}
```

hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small sample that could help you find a common implementation logic for multiple enums.

```
interface Doable<B>{
    B doStuff(Number a);

    String getCategory()
}


enum StatsFromMachine1 implements Doable<String> {
    ABC{

        @Override
        public String doStuff(Number a) {               
            return Integer.toString(a.intValue() + 3);
        }

    };

    @Override
    public String getCategory() {
        return "S1";
    }
}

enum StatsFromMachine2 implements Doable<String>{
    X(1.4), Y(2.86), Z(0.1);

    private Double d;

    @Override
    public String doStuff(Number x) {
        return Double.toString(x.doubleValue() * this.d);
    }

    private StatsFromMachine2(Double d) {
        this.d = d;
    }

    @Override
    public String getCategory() {
        return "S2";
    }
}
```

When the enums implement the same interface, then it's easy to write code that is applicable to all of them. Actually, this kind of abstraction doesn't care, whether the implementation is given by an enum or something else.

```
public static String doStuffWithEnums(){
    Collection<Doable<String>> collection = Arrays.asList(StatsFromMachine1.values());
    collection.addAll(Arrays.asList(StatsFromMachine2.values()));

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for(Doable<String> d : collection){
        sb.append(d.doStuff(5.0));

        if(d.getCategory().equals("S1")){ // alternatively use an instanceOf check
            sb.append(((StatsFromMachine1)d).name());
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OK I've figured it out 
Thank you for the help and you will get +1 after I review your content :)
so basically I have `enum E1` that implement `interface I1` 
To iterate over the `enum` members "generically" what I did is :

```
public static void parse_log_with_enum(I1 ... Is)
{
    for (I1 i1 : Is) {
        // do something with i1
    }   
}
```